# How to separate sets of numbers onto separate lines

Tags: php, newline

**About the script:**

The script below will create 300 **sets** of random characters.

What is presently happening, is that it creates them but shows them all on one line, in one big chunk.

With all the searching and testing I've done to try and achieve this, I have had no success.

I would like to know which code and where to put it, so that each SET (300) of 15 characters long, will show and be saved to file.

**Here is my script:**

```
<?php

function GetID($x){

$characters = array_merge(range('A','Z'),range('a','z'),range(2,9));
shuffle($characters);


for($x=0;$x<=299;$x++){

}

for (; strlen($ReqID)<$x;){
$ReqID .= $characters[mt_rand(0, count($characters))];
}


return $ReqID;
}     

$ReqID .= GetID(5);
$ReqID .= "-";
$ReqID .= GetID(5);
$ReqID .= "-";
$ReqID .= GetID(5);


echo $ReqID;


$fh = fopen("file.txt","a+");
fwrite($fh, ("$ReqID")."\n");
fclose($fh);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify you `GetID` function to insert a new line at every 15th character:

```
function GetID($x){
   $characters = array_merge(range('A','Z'),range('a','z'),range(2,9));
   shuffle($characters);
   $ReqID='';
   for ($i=0; strlen($ReqID)<300; $i++){
      $ReqID .= $characters[mt_rand(0, count($characters))];
      if ($i>0 && $i%15 == 0)
         $ReqID .= "\n";
   }
   return $ReqID;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The modulo operator (`%`) will let you check for regular intervals.

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 299; $x++) {
    echo $characters[$x];
    if ($x % 15 == 14) {
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. It works to a certain extent for a certain amount of 15 character sequences by putting a space between them, but then stops and produces a very long string at the end. It doesn't echo/write to file in their own seperate lines.

Comment: @Fred - You are only putting 60 characters into the array so the `299` should be `59` or better yet `$x < count($characters)`.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work neither. I might try and insert a carriage return at every "x-position" then write back to the file. It's getting way too late at this point tonight.

Comment: My original goal was, to create a list of 300 sets of random characters (numbers-letters) approx. 15 chars.long and have them on their own line, one underneath the other, echo it to screen and write the same to a file.

Comment: Loop as many random lines as you want. In it, shuffle the chars and print out the first 15 using [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) followed by a newline.

Comment: I tried to do a complete rewrite, but I wasn't successful. I don't know where I went wrong and spent more than 5 hours on it, and honestly don't have a clue where it's not working.

Comment: You might want to start a new question with your latest code if you can boil it down to one problem. SO is more a "I have this specific problem" site rather than "I need a program to do X. Can you write it?" If you can ask specifics, you'll get help.

Comment: I understand David. I don't expect others to write my code. I always like to spend time in trying to figure it out myself first, before asking for help. :)